# Which version of Kibana is to be used with Elastic Search 5.1?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elasticsearch-5, kibana-5

I am confused in choosing the right version of Kibana with Elastic Search 5.1.

Is it necessary to use Kibana 5.1 with Elastic Search 5.1 or can I use any version? Please suggest.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in the [official Kibana documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/setup.html#elasticsearch-version):

> Kibana should be configured to run against an Elasticsearch node of the same version. This is the officially supported configuration.
>
> Running different major version releases of Kibana and Elasticsearch (e.g. Kibana 5.x and Elasticsearch 2.x) is not supported, nor is running a minor version of Kibana that is newer than the version of Elasticsearch (e.g. Kibana 5.1 and Elasticsearch 5.0).

However, in order to facilitate an upgrade process where Elasticsearch is upgraded first, you can run a minor version of Elasticsearch that is higher than Kibana (e.g. Kibana 5.0 and Elasticsearch 5.1). But this should only be temporary